# How to iterate over every two columns of a data frame in python using a function?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, function, loops

There is an excel file that I have to read and do some process on every two columns of it, and eventually concatenate them vertically in a two columns dataframe.

I code the process for the column 0 and 1,
Now I am struggling to generate a function to do the same for all the two sets of columns.

I first chose the first two columns from excel as bellow

```
  data1 = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', usecols=[0,1],parse_dates=True)
```

How can I generate data1 to data5 from columns(0,1) (2,3) (4,5) (6,7) and do pd.concat([data1,data2,data3,data4,data5])

I can’t shear the Excel file,however it looks like

```
      stocks = [('2021-01-04', 113.4377, '2021-01-04','Nan'),
           ('2021-01-07', 125.8316, '2021-01-07',127.8212),
           ('2021-01-14', 108.4792, '2021-01-14',111.0318),
           ('2021-01-21', 99.584, '2021-01-21',144.6129),
            ]
df = pd.DataFrame(stocks,columns =['DateA', 'StockA', 'DateB', 'StockB'])
df
```

Comment: Can you share your desired output ?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the entire dataset, loop on df.columns and save all datasets in a dictionary:

```
data = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', parse_dates=True)

d={}

for i in range(5):
    d['data_' + str(i+1)] = data[data.columns[i*2:i*2+2]]
```

And finally concat all the datasets:

```
result = pd.concat([i for i in d.keys()])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn’t follow your code. If change the “data” in your code with the “df” ,the sample in my question. How can I return each 'data_' + str(i+1)  Thank you